Movie with children chased by adults dressed in black
I saw this film as a kid, I was probably 6 or 7 so this was around 1986-1989.
It was programmed as a children's film, so my mom took me.
I remember only certain scenes from this film. My guess is that throughout the film, these children who were the "good guys" of the film were chased by tall adults dressed in black. Maybe they escaped an orphanage? I'm not quite sure.
Anyways. Among the group of children, is a young girl dressed in pink. Throughout their adventures, which take place in various places like a road movie (plane or balloon? then boat? then car? something like that), the team of kids and the girl in pink invariably outsmart the darkly clad adults, and to such a ridiculous extent that in the end (spoiler alert! to a movie I don't know the title of), one of the adults becomes nuts and committed to an insane asylum.
While in the asylum, a doctor asks him through drawings to tell them what happened and when presented a drawing of a boat, he draws the girl in pink inside the boat with a pink pen. When presented with a picture of an island, he draws the girl in pink on it, obsessed as he is by his own defeat and its peculiarly innocent look.
I think it might be a European film more than a US film (I grew up in the Paris area), and it might have been made between 1960 and 1988. Sorry I can't be any more specific but someone with good knowledge of children movies from this period might be able to name it.
EDIT: After doing a lot of searching, I think it is possible, but not certain, that the memory is actually of two films that would have been programmed together. One of them might be Czech film Ukradená vzducholod and maybe another one by the same director or also Czech? The part with the little girl was definitely in color in my memory.

It might chivi chivi bang bang

I guess the film you are looking for is Momo. This fantasy movie was produced 1986. The protagonist of the story - a little girl - is hunted by men in dark suits.
